# Load JSON object instead of JSON file in Create JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, createjs

I have been loading the JSON file in create JS like below code

```
        var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
        loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
        loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
        loader.loadFile({src:"myjsonfile.json", type:"spritesheet", id:"myID"}, true);
        loader.loadManifest(nameVar.properties.manifest);
```

But I dont want to load the JSON file , instead I want to include the JSON object directly.

Will the below code can replace the above thing

```
var loader= JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');
```

Comment: no, your new code will override the LoadQueue class, you can store your json in another variable and reference that

Comment: @madalinivascu I want to get ride of loading the json file. I want to add the json object to a variable and then use it

Comment: then this code will work